# OL numbering in chrome not left-aligning, appearing on the right

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-lists, css-float

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with OL numbering in Chrome, here's my markup:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="block left">
      <span class="block">Main Title<span class="alert">!</span></span>
      <input type='text' name='title-1' />
    </div>

    <div class="block left">
      <span class="block">Subtitle<span class="alert">!</span></span>
      <input type='text' name='title-2' />
   </div>

    <div class="block left">
      <span class="block">Add Image<span class="alert">!</span></span>
      <input type='file' name='image' size='30' />
    </div>
  </li> 
<ol>
```

The classes used are:

```
    .block { display:block; }  
    .left { float:left; }  
    .alert { color:red; }
```

The problem I'm having is that I need the number of my OL to appear to the LEFT of the LI's contents, but Chrome seems to attribute some kind of float property to the numbers, making it appear on the right.

Can anyone provide any assistance on this matter?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are floating an element inside of a non floating element.  Try assigning float to both the ol & li elements (also set their width to 100%)

Answer (score 3):

```
ol li { margin-left: 60px; list-style-type: decimal; }
```

will make the numbers visible.

Wrapping the tags inside li-elements with `<div class="wrap">` and apply this css to it:

```
.wrap { display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 12px; }
```

will fix your problem --> http://jsfiddle.net/GpfYk/2/

`position: relative; top: 12px;` makes the position nicer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a `span` with a class of "block" inside the `li`, and both are being floated. If you remove the class of block from the `span`, it should fix the issue.

Or, if you wish to keep the elements inline, try setting them to `display: inline-block` and remove the "left" class to float them as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jglovier/zshPr/